# How to get time sets by user or automatically ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, time, offline

I want to get value of time sets by user or automatically , is there any way to do it in ios ?

Value that i want for :

Settings > General > Date&Time > Set Automatically

or

I'm looking get correct time while there is no internet connection.When i'm set the automatically in settings,the time sets correctly by phone so is it a way that same value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access that setting value. You need to rely upon a network based time to be sure of actual time.